# Bluetooth external keyboard for my iPad

Tags: ipad, keyboard

How can I stop my external keyboard from sending a text when I hit return?  I want it to just bring up the next line but it sends the text instead.  Originally, when hitting return, another line came up but now it sends the text...I must've caused this somehow but now I want it to return to the original function of just bringing up the next line.  Thank you.

I use Messages to text...

Comment: Please include what app your text is "sending" in. Messages? Mail? Whatsapp? Hangouts?

Answer (score 1):

Press <kbd>alt/option</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd> or <kbd>control</kbd>+<kbd>return</kbd> to enter a new line instead of sending.